# Criteria API doesn't execute query

Tags: java, spring, criteria, criteria-api

I've got a DAO, which filters lists.

```
    public List<User> filterUser(UserView userView) {
    List<User> userList;
    Long officeId = userView.officeId;
    String firstName = userView.firstName;
    String secondName = userView.secondName;
    String middleName = userView.middleName;
    String position = userView.position;
    String docCode = userView.docCode;
    String citizenshipCode = userView.citizenshipCode;

    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<User> userQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(User.class);
    Root<User> userRoot = userQuery.from(User.class);
    Join<User, Document> docJoin = userRoot.join("document");
    Join<Document, DocType> docTypeJoin = docJoin.join("docType");
    Join<Document, Country> countryJoin = docJoin.join("country");

    userQuery.select(userRoot);
    userQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(userRoot.get("office"), officeId));

    if (firstName != null) {
        userQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(userRoot.get("firstName"), firstName));
    }
    if (secondName != null) {
        userQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(userRoot.get("secondName"), secondName));
    }
    if (middleName != null) {
        userQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(userRoot.get("middleName"), middleName));
    }
    if (position != null) {
        userQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(userRoot.get("position"), position));
    }

    if (docCode != null) {
        userQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(docTypeJoin.get("code"), docCode));
    }

    if (citizenshipCode != null) {
        userQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(countryJoin.get("code"), citizenshipCode));
    }

    userList = em.createQuery(userQuery).getResultList();
    return userList;
}
```

If I request fields `officeId`,`firstName`, `secondName` and etc everything works correctly.

Problem with `docCode` and `citizenshipCode`. For example when I send `officeId` with `docCode` a filter works only for `docCode` and nothing for `officeId`.

In case I change the rows in places like this:

```
userQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(docTypeJoin.get("code"), docCode));
```

and after

```
  userQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(userRoot.get("office"), officeId));
```

I've got list with only `officeId` and nothing for`docCode`.

Comment: What does the javadoc of where say? https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html#where-javax.persistence.criteria.Expression-

Comment: Thank you, I have not seen this before. But why sometimes its works correctly like it doesnt replaces restrictions and how can I fix it in my case?

Comment: It only works correctly if you pass a single criterion. Turn SQL logging on, and you'll see what SQL query is being executed in each of the tests.

Comment: So I need to create only List with predicates and after just execute it.

Comment: Yes, that's one way of doing. Or you can create a conjunction (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#conjunction--), and then use `and` (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#and-javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate...-) to create a new one with additional clauses